# How to solve combination riddle question with a given scenario

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

A combination lock has 20 numbers. To open the lock, rotate clockwise to the first number, counter-clockwise past the first number to the second number and then clockwise to the third number. How many different combinations are there if you CANNOT repeat a number in the combination

my work:

so first you have 3 spaces _ _ _
second, you have a combination lock of 20 numbers so first space is 20,second is 19,third is 18,so

20x19x18=6840

the answer is 6840

Is this the correct way of solving this problem?

Comment: The way I interpret the problem, yes I agree with your answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz I had another ,which stack exchange wont let me post,I was wondering if you could help me with it . Heres the question:A combination lock has 40 numbers. To open the lock, rotate clockwise to the first number counter-clockwise past the first number to the second number and then clockwise to the third number. How many possible combinations are there if the middle number must be between 10 and 15. so I basically know theirs 3 spaces. First two will be 40,39 and the third one must be between 10 and 15,so would I multiply 10x15 and get 150 for the third space?

Comment: I upvoted not only to reverse a downvote but also because the OP showed good work.  I'm guessing that the downvote was because the original question was poorly formatted - Personally, I don't think that new users should be downvoted re poor formatting.

Comment: What do you mean - "...which stack exchange won't let me post..."?  Do you mean that for some reason your mathSE posting priveleges have been suspended?  Alternatively, do you mean that you have been discouraged from asking two somewhat unrelated questions in one mathSE query?  If the latter, simply create a separate mathSE query.

Comment: With respect to the 2nd (more complicated) question, which occurs in your comment to  JMoravitz, your reasoning is close but wrong.  First of all, I interpret "between 10 and 15" to signify 6 possible choices.  Secondly, you **nicely** changed the problem so that the restricted choice is the 3rd #, rather than the "middle #".  This alteration is both valid and **elegant.**  ...see next comment

Comment: @Ranveer_18 the second problem relies on multiplication principle just like the first.  The point of it though is that you need to recognize that you don't need to define the steps in chronological order.  Here it helps to choose the number for the middle *first* and *then* pick the start number and then the end number.  Also... "*between 10 and 15*" that would be having picked the number $10$, the number $11$, the number $12$,... on to $15$.  There are six options there for what the middle number is... not $150$.  There was no reason to multiply $10$ and $15$.

Comment: Third, the computation of $40 \times 39 \times 6$ is **flat wrong** because of the $40 \times 39 = 1560$ possible combinations of the 1st and 2nd numbers, they will **not** all permit exactly 6 choices re the 3rd number.  You have to **break down** the 1560 possibilities into **three** groups.  (1) G1 : 2 #'s from the 10-15 range are used (2) G2: 1 # from the 10-15 range are used (3) G3: 0 # from the 10-15 range are used.  Then, you have to compute G1, G2, and G3.  Final answer will be $(G1 \times 4) + (G2 \times 5) + (G3 \times 6).$

Comment: For completion, re previous comments, $G1 = 6 \times 5 = 30.$  Superficially, it would seem that $G2 = 34 \times 6.$ This is wrong, because you have to distinguish between (for example) 1st # = 40, 2nd # = 15, and 1st # = 15, 2nd # = 40.  Therefore, $G2 = 2 \times 34 \times 6 = 408.$  Finally, $G3 = 34 \times 33 = 1122.$

Comment: @JMoravitz I carelessly overlooked your intervening comment/approach.  I **agree**.  The analysis is more **elegant** if you make the *restricted* choice **first** rather than last.